# Jquery click and hover events on different elements to effect on same element not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

I have problem with the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#icon2').click(
  function(){ $('#st1').animate({top:'-10px'},500);}
  );
  $('#down1').hover(
  function(){ $('#st1').stop(true, false).animate({bottom:'+=250px'},10000,'linear');}, 
  function(){ $('#st1').stop(true, false).animate({bottom:'-=0px'},10000,'linear');}
  );
});
```

From the below picture,

**#down1** is the ***down-arrow*** below the text

**#icon2** is the ***about*** icon

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is when I hover on the down-arrow, the text should scroll down and when I mouseout, the scrolling should stop. And when I click on about icon, the text should scroll back to its default position.

But the problem here is only one effect is working either hover or click but not both at once.

Please help where I am doing it wrong with some detailed explanation if possible.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g1patnaik/ycvfrgwd/1/

Comment: could you please add a jsfiddle ? or a snippet ?

Comment: i dont want to see the live code... i want to have a plattform where i can add some things to may provide you with a solution :) i dont need the stuff around :)

Comment: @Dwza http://jsfiddle.net/0f3hdm9h/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0f3hdm9h/4/#&togetherjs=mSVJvJg7cH

Comment: your animation is not really running in your provided fiddle. check this fiddle here and set it up right: http://jsfiddle.net/wu2djh98/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g1patnaik/ycvfrgwd/1/ Hi this is corrected one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64111/discussion-between-jeevan-patnaik-and-dwza).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you have made a lil mistake...

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#icon2').click(
  function(){ $('#st1').stop(true, false).animate({bottom:'0px'},500);}
  );
  $('#down1').hover(
  function(){ $('#st1').stop(true, false).animate({bottom:'+=250px'},10000,'linear');}, 
  function(){ $('#st1').stop(true, false).animate({bottom:'-=0px'},10000,'linear');}
  );
});
```

I just changed the animate `top` to animate `bottom`. In your hover you set up the bottom style so you actualy should do the same on the about click. Otherwise the bottom pos will be still present. I would test this, but i cant since you only provided me with your orininal code page ;)

Actually this works: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g1patnaik/jz5227g6/4/)

(EDIT: changed the ops comment in the source)

Comment: I have changed it to up..and here is the jfiddlet. http://jsfiddle.net/0f3hdm9h/1/ but still not working! :(

Comment: yes it works and by adding in click function stop(true,false) to avoid delay